# How to click on unordered list using Selenium JAVA

Tags: java, selenium, dynamic, unordered

Please help me to write xpath to select the `Name address Maintenance` from the HTML below. It's an unordered list, where the id changes dynamically every time. I used

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Name Address Maintenance')]")).click();
```

but seeing the error message

> Unable to locate element using the xpath provided

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content" id="ui-id-290" tabindex="0" role="combobox" style="display: block; top: 112px; left: 138.6px; width: 231px;">
    <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-318" tabindex="-1">Accounting/Closing</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-319" tabindex="-1">Account Maintenance</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-320" tabindex="-1">Account Opening</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-321" tabindex="-1">Account Review</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-322" tabindex="-1">Administration</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-323" tabindex="-1">Advance Distribution</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-324" tabindex="-1">Asset Movement</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-325" tabindex="-1">Cash Receipt</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-326" tabindex="-1">Cash Disbursement</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-327" tabindex="-1">Court Accounting</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-328" tabindex="-1">Loan Request</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-329" tabindex="-1">Name Address Maintenance</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-330" tabindex="-1">Alternate Account Opening</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item"  tabindex="-1">Trust Forms</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I suspect the problem is not the xpath, but synchronization. Instead of `findElement`, try waiting for it: `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(...)).click()`

Answer (score 0):

Below is working fine for me for the program

```
WebElement typeBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id='1_s_1_l_SR_Type_New_']"));
typeBox.click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='1_SR_Type_New_']")).sendKeys("Name Address Maintenance");
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there are changes when we selenium dont find elements directly and so we need to start from parent node.

Secondly, its always better to use complete text (not just contains), try this, it should work :

*driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul/li[text()='Name Address Maintenance']")).click();*

Answer (score -1):

Try this. It works

```
//*[@class='ui-menu-item' and contains(text(),'Name Address Maintenance')]
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response...I have tried with 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='ui-menu-item' and contains(text(),'Name Address Maintenance')]"));
but seeing the below error 
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@class='ui-menu-item' and contains(text(),'Name Address Maintenance')]"}
  (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.108)

It's Type drop down box where I need to select the Name address Maintenance value from the list in Unordered list which is dynamic everytime.

Comment: Try this , //*[@class='ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content']//*[@class='ui-menu-item' and contains(text(),'Name Address Maintenance')]

Comment: why do you think this xpath is any better than the one he is already using? also `//*` is always a bad idea, regardless.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
//child::li[@class='ui-menu-item' and contains(text(),'Name Address Maintenance')]
```

or

```
.//li[@class='ui-menu-item' and contains(text(),'Name Address Maintenance')]
```

Comment: Thanks Vel unfortunately both of this didn't work for me. I have tried with below and it worked. Thanks for all your support.